# Swift: func return type inheritting class and conforming one or more protocols

Tags: swift, oop, swift3, swift-protocols

From an external library I've got the following scenario.

The protocol and base class:

```
protocol P1 {
    // P1 Stuff
}

class A {
    // A Stuff
}
```

Then there is an extension, which causes my troubles. It is defined for the combination of types `P1` and `A`.

```
extension P1 where Self : A {
    public func myDesiredFunc() {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

And finally there are the implementations `B1` - `Bn`, which I use.

```
class B1 : A, P1 {
}
class B2 : A, P1 {
}
...
```

In my code I need to put together instances of B-classes and work with them. The problem is, that I need to use the extension func `myDesiredFunc()`.  So I need somehow define, that the array type is something like `[(A & P1)]` and the return type of producing funciton is `(A & P1)` as well.

However, with this code:

```
func createBeeInstance() -> (A & P1) {
    if something {
        return B1()
    } else if something {
        return B2()
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Non-protocol type 'A' cannot be used within a protocol composition.

Is there a way to say that the return type is a composition of class and protocol? I'm not able to change the scenario because it's an external library.

Comment: you can use generics `func createBeeInstance<T: P1>() -> T where T: A {} `

Comment: No, I can't. Because the type `T` would be inferred when using the func. There is no such type, which I could put the func result into. Consider, that i need to put the `createBeeInstance()` results into one array.On top of that, types B1, B2... would not be able to cast to type T.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to define a protocol that defines the essential nature of objects of type `A` (let's call the new protocol `Aable`), and make the `A` type conform to it:

```
class A: Aable {
    // A stuff
}
```

You could then constrain the `P1` protocol extension with `Aable` instead of `A`:

```
extension P1 where Self : Aable {
    func myDesiredFunc() {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

That would allow you to use protocol composition for the return type of a function...

```
func createBeeInstance(useB1: Bool) -> (Aable & P1) {
    return useB1 ? B1() : B2()
}
```

...as well as for the element type of an array:

```
var things = [Aable & P1]()

for i in 1...5 {
    let b = createBeeInstance(useB1: i % 2 == 0)
    things.append(b)
}

for thing in things {
    thing.myDesiredFunc()
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but, as I wrote above,  `A`, `P1`, `B1` - `Bn` are from an external library. With changing the library, there are many simple solutions. What I'm seeking for is a way, how to tell the compiler, that the result will be a subclass of `A` that conforms protocol `P1`. Like it is possible with two protocols in your solution. Therefore, your code is not the answer. I'm afraid, that the correct answer is: "No, there is no such way."

Comment: Can you add the `Aable` protocol to a subclass of `A`, and then make that the superclass of `B1` and `B2`?

Comment: No. That makes this question a tricky one ;) That's why I'm sharing the problem with you guys.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift** **4**:

^_^
it's possible now to compose class and protocol in swift 4 so modifying the previous snippets to this should work

```
class A {
// A Stuff
required init () {}
}
protocol P1 {
// P1 Stuff
}

class B1 : A {}
class B3: P1 {}
class B2 : A, P1 {}

func createBeeInstance<T: P1 & A>(type: T.Type) -> T  {
return type.init()
 }

var things = [P1 & A]() // still Element has to be P1 as well
let f = createBeeInstance(type: B2.self)
//let f1 = createBeeInstance(type: B1.self) // will error
//let f2 = createBeeInstance(type: B3.self) // will error

things.append(f) // is fine
```

--- OLD Way which did not work ---

You may  use this way , 
having  the Sample you provided with modifying class A to have init

```
class A {
    // A Stuff
    required init () {}
}
```

modifying createBee method to

```
func createBeeInstance<T: P1>(type: T.Type) -> T where T: A {
    return type.init()
}
```

this way you will provide the type as an input e.g. `B1.self`

for array we can provide typealieased generic

```
typealias B<T:P1> = T where T: A

var things = [B<A>]() // still Element has to be P1 as well 
let f = createBeeInstance(type: B2.self)
let f1 = createBeeInstance(type: B1.self)
things.append(f)
```

Comment: I like the typealias trick. However, I can't use this either. The problem with the generic version of `createBeeInstance` is that in my case, the caller of `createBeeInstance` does not know, which of the `B1` - `Bn` classes the func will return.

Comment: Second thing is, that the typealias trick does not work. When I create the array exactly as you write and than insert manually created instances `B1()` and `B2()`, calling `things[0].someP1Method()` raises compilator error saying _Value of type 'A' has no member 'someP1Method()'_. Which is strange.

Comment: I also tried to make the `B<A>` be a return type of `createBeeInstance()`, but there was always problem with casting any `Bi` type to the `T` type. The compilator just couldn't decide, which of the the `B`s should be used for inferring the `T`

Comment: yeah my assumption is not correct.  B<A> still only recognized as A.

Comment: EDIT Swift 4: Nice feature. Nevertheless, I cannot mark it as an answer since you must specify the output type when calling `createBeeInstance`. In my case, the particular returned `B` class should be determined inside the function. But thanks for your update. Hope it will help other to other people.